# Definition of Statistical Model

Tags: probability-theory, definition, mathematical-modeling

From Wikipedia:

*"...a statistical model is usually thought of as a pair $\mathcal{(S,P)}$, where $\mathcal{S}$ is the set of possible observations, i.e. the sample space, and $\mathcal{P}$ is a set of probability distributions on $\mathcal{S}$.*

*The intuition behind this definition is as follows. It is assumed that there is a "true" probability distribution induced by the process that generates the observed data. We choose $\mathcal{P}$ to represent a set (of distributions) which contains a distribution that adequately approximates the true distribution."*

I would like to have som clarity in regard to what is meant by **process** in this context. The observable data is generated as a result of *reality*/*our world* so does **process** refer to *reality*/*our world* in its entirety? Because *reality*/*our world* is after all what generates the observable data.

Or, does it refer to any process in *reality*/*our world* which generates the observable data. If this is the case then I struggle with the fact that this definition says "**process**" in singular as if there is only one **process** in *reality*/*our world* that generates the observable data. If a **process** is an abstract human made description of some aspect of *reality*/*our world* which generates observable data, then isn't it possible to imagine an infinite number of possible **processes** all of which on their own can describe the observable data? All those **processes** could still induce the same "true" probability distribution that generates the observed data, but every **process** could represent some specific aspects of *reality*/*our world*. Right??

Comment: A statistical model generally only models a specific situation. For instance, rolling a die, or flipping a coin. That there is only one process that generates the data is part of the definition of the situation being modelled. If I am modelling flipping a coin 100 times, i don't care about what tea leaf patterns Aunt Tilly finds in her tea. They have no impact on my coin flips.

Comment: @ Paul Sinclair if we are flipping a coin or rolling a die we can represent one trial/random experiment with a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F, P})$. Execute $(\Omega, \mathcal{F, P})$ once and you get one outcome. So, does "process" mean random experiment then???

Comment: The probability space is not the process. "It cannot be executed" A process *can be modelled by* a "Random Variable": a function from a set of experiments to their outcomes in $\scr S$, the sample space. The process itself is whatever physical activity results in the outcome. The random variable is the mathematical object that we use to model it.

Comment: @ Paul Sinclair Straight from Wikipedia: "a random experiment is modeled by a mathematical construct known as a probability space. A mathematical description of an experiment consists of three parts $(\Omega, \mathcal{S, P})$. An outcome is the result of a single execution of the model.